Android Studio (version unknown)
I have 2 lines in Android Studio when I run flutter doctor. One of them is fine, but the other one says "Android Studio (version unknown)." I deleted Android Studio from my Mac and reinstalled it. Even though I deleted Android Studio, it still shows "Android Studio (version unknown)."
I've tried all possible solutions, but I couldn't find anything that works.

I was having the same problem and Android Studio was still showing up in the trash. I erased the contents of the trash and it worked.
